# Only 3 rows from the table from each record in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a large table I must find 3 unique id record from each status i have in clause where. Nice when if finds 3 records he stops looking for this status and will look for the next ones up to 3. The table is very large, I care about efficiency and the search will be used many times.

I have :

| ID | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | d |
| 2 | d |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | a |
| 3 | a |
| 3 | b |
| 3 | e |
| 4 | a |
| 4 | b |
| 5 | a |
| 5 | b |

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM (
  select
    id,
    status,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY status) as rn,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY status ORDER BY id) as rne
  from x 
  where status in ('a', 'b' , 'e') 
) a 
WHERE rn <= 1 and rne <=3;
```

This code is looking for records too long, I need to have something more efficient

result I need:

| id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 3 | a |
| 4 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | b |
| 3 | e |

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. It doesn't have unique IDs in the result.

Comment: unique id for status, believe me it doesn't make sense to me either but the result is shown correctly :)

Comment: What's the query plan?  What indexes exist?  How fast does the query run?  How fast do you need it to run?  Can you pre-compute results?  Or does the query really need to be run live each time?

Comment: index for IDs and date (and many more but not useles for this query) status without index, on the develop base is 2 minute for 3 samples IDs for 3  status but this develop base have only 1%  records  from production (and all is fake), on production we must find 3 samples ids for 50 status. Must be run live, we can only use subquery or with clause

Answer (score 1):

Try this (you need a column to order, here I added "rn" but it could be a date):

```
with data(rn,id,status) as (
    select 1, 1, 'a' from dual union all 
    select 2, 1, 'b' from dual union all 
    select 3, 1, 'b' from dual union all 
    select 4, 1, 'd' from dual union all 
    select 5, 2, 'd' from dual union all 
    select 6, 2, 'b' from dual union all 
    select 7, 2, 'b' from dual union all 
    select 8, 2, 'c' from dual union all 
    select 9, 2, 'b' from dual union all 
    select 10, 3, 'a' from dual union all 
    select 11, 3, 'a' from dual union all 
    select 12, 3, 'b' from dual union all 
    select 13, 3, 'e' from dual union all 
    select 14, 4, 'a' from dual union all 
    select 15, 4, 'b' from dual union all 
    select 16, 5, 'a' from dual union all 
    select 17, 5, 'b' from dual 
)
select id, status
from (
    select id, status,
        dense_rank() over(partition by status order by rn) as rnk
    from (
        select 
            rn,
            dense_rank() over(partition by status, id order by rn) as rnk1,
            id, status
        from (
            select rn, id, status
            from (
                select rn, id, status
                    , lag(status) over(order by rn) as prev_status
                from data
            )
            where status <> prev_status or prev_status is null
        )
    )
    where rnk1 = 1
)
where rnk <= 3
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a combination of Group By to eliminate duplicates and a simple Count() Over() analytic function to get just three rows per STATUS.

```sql
WITH  
    tbl (ID, STATUS) AS 
        (
            Select  1,  'a' From Dual Union All 
            Select  1,  'b' From Dual Union All 
            Select  1,  'b' From Dual Union All 
            Select  1,  'd' From Dual Union All 
            Select  2,  'd' From Dual Union All 
            Select  2,  'b' From Dual Union All 
            Select  2,  'b' From Dual Union All 
            Select  2,  'c' From Dual Union All 
            Select  2,  'b' From Dual Union All 
            Select  3,  'a' From Dual Union All 
            Select  3,  'a' From Dual Union All 
            Select  3,  'b' From Dual Union All 
            Select  3,  'e' From Dual Union All 
            Select  4,  'a' From Dual Union All 
            Select  4,  'b' From Dual Union All 
            Select  5,  'a' From Dual Union All 
            Select  5,  'b' From Dual 
        )
Select ID, STATUS
From
    ( Select  t.STATUS, t.ID, Count(t.ID) OVER(PARTITION BY STATUS ORDER BY ID) "RN" 
      From tbl t
      Group By STATUS, ID
      Order By STATUS, ID 
    )
Where RN <= 3 And STATUS IN('a', 'b', 'e')

        ID STATUS
---------- ------
         1 a
         3 a
         4 a
         1 b
         2 b
         3 b
         3 e
```